# Throws Advice in Spring

Tags: spring

If the business method is catching the exception not re thrown, will the throw advice would be invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the advice applies to the business method, the throw advice will not be invoked, since it doesn't get see the exception.

If you want to "have your cake (or exception) and eat it" separate out the business logic into another method. e.g.

```
public void myBusinessLogic()
{
  try
  {
     myBusinessLogicImpl();  
  }
  catch (BusinessLogicException ex)
  {
  }
}
```

You can then add throws advice to the `myBusinessLogicImpl()` method, as well as swallowing up the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring AOP (most cases), aspect will no be invoked. Essentially the code would look like this:

Business method:

```
public void businessMethod() {
  try {
    doSomething();
  } catch(BusinessException e) {
    //handle and not rethrow
  }
```

Aspect:

```
try {
  businessMethod();
} catch(BusinessException e) {
  //Aspect advice
}
```

As you can see there is no way aspect can ever "see" the exception. If you really want `BusinessException` to be intercepted even though it does not escape from `businessMethod()`, pure AspectJ instead of Spring AOP might do the trick. It integrates nicely with Spring, but some hardcore steps need to be performed (*compile-* or *load-time-weaving*) first.